# Total count is wrong in commentThread in youtube data api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There seems to be a bug in the youtube data api and i don't know where to report it. In the get help section it was mentioned to ask here.

The bug:

CommentThread api does not give correct value of **pageInfo.totalResults** . for example, when requesting this url `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key={{key}}&part=snippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCGXaE9EsaPbG8YkSm7lBFBA` only gives **totalResults = 20** and when increasing **maxResults** to 100, **totalResults=96** and **resultsPerPage=100**

Comment: check the issue forum i think that was reported years ago. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B&pli=1

Comment: I tried but couldn't find it. So i thought  posting this question would be a better approach